# received memory warning then crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash

**I want to display multiple images in scrollview when images are more than 70 application will crash and display received memory error.I have get the images from document Directory**

I have tried -

```
 UIScrollView *MyScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    int x=5,y=15;

    for (int i = 0; i < imgarr.count; i++)
    {
        if(x<=211)
        {

        UIImage* imagePath = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path_array objectAtIndex:i]];

        imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 77, 75)];
        imgView.image=imagePath;

            imgeBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imgeBtn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 93, 110);
            [imgeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            imgeBtn.tag=i;
            x+=103;

        }
        else
        {
            x=5;
            y+=130;


        UIImage* imagePath = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[path_array objectAtIndex:i]];

        imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 77, 75)];
        imgView.image=imagePath;

            imgeBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imgeBtn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 93, 110);
            [imgeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            imgeBtn.tag=i;
            x+=103;

        }
        [MyScroll addSubview:imgeBtn];
        [MyScroll addSubview:imgView];
         MyScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, y+120);
```

How can I display multiple images in scrollview?

Comment: can you please explain why you are using if(x<=211) ? Are you trying to showing all images in Horizontal or Vertical ?

Comment: Scrollview is not a better approach for showing multiple images. UICollectionView is better approach to show image because its reusable. In Scrollview each time you allocating memory, however application will crash or will be take too load.

Comment: i have trying both UIScrolView and UICollectionView but result are same.

Comment: it will be better to use uicollection view in place of uiscroll view as in uicollection view the we are able to create a reusable cell.

Comment: @sohil please consume your bounty in a better way, you are consuming Grace period now

Comment: @sohil Remove scroll view & use collection view

Comment: Because scroll view continuously hold the memory & collection view will release the memory as needed

Comment: Thanks @KaushikMovaliya for give response of very old question. So what is the solution? Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

The advice others have given to switch to a `UICollectionView` is good, but it has missed the real flaw in your code: the method `imageNamed:` of `UIImage` is keeping all 70 of your images in memory forever. Per the docs:

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to
>   ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should
>   instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will
>   keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially
>   improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Switching to this method will prevent the crashes, if you only load into memory the images that you need. UICollectionView makes this trivial, since you can only load image when the collection view asks you to fill out a cell object in its datasource's `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexpath:` method.

Answer (score 5):

```
Create custom class of collection view cell 
and You can pass image name in array. 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *Collection;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.Collection registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self.Collection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 4;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell * cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYZ.png"];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating and keep adding the images which causing the memory crash as all the images taking the device memory, There are many solution which build for showing the images and best is using the UICollectionView which load only the images which is showing the screen. You go for any good tutorial which can show you how to do it, here is the [reference](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

Comment: sorry it's not work i have use UIColllectionView , UITabelview and Scollview all are same result.I have get the images from document Directory

Answer (score 2):

Maybe NSCache can help you.

1
When you are displaying image at index 10.You can cache image 5-9 and 11-16 to NSCache/

2
When scrollView start Scrolling, get image from NSCache you need,and remove the object you doesn't need to display.

3 
I think this can be efficient. Apple provide a demo how they handle the massive assets using caches and UICollectionView.You take a look at it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this same issue which i have resolved using below simple line.

`instead of using this:`

```
[UIImage imagedNamed:@"yourImage"];
```

`try using this:`

```
[yourCell.imageview setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"]]];
```

i hope it would solve your problem as by using `imageWithContentsOfFile` releases memory. so you won't get `Memory Warning`

**UPDATE**
You may also display images from any Remote URL and also from your application's document directory using other methods of `UIImage Class`

do tell if it helps

Comment: `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` *does* consume memory -- it's just that it won't be permanent. Furthermore, just because you *can* get images from any URL using this method doesn't mean you *should*; this method is synchronous, and therefore should never be called from the main thread in such a scenario.

Comment: yes, and that's why the questionnaire had problem. this memory will be released. and secondly using URL depends upon the questionnaire logic.. its just an option buddy. and one more thing. did you just downvoted and commented this to justify your downvote?

Comment: You say "does not consume memory," not "doesn't stay in memory after it's been released." There's a big difference. As for the "Remote URL" thing, it's only an option if you don't care about the quality of your software. The Apple documentation on similar methods (`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`) *explicitly* says not to do this.

Comment: can't you just edit my answer instead of downvoting it...?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with UITableView . Suppose you have n number of Images then -

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }
        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {
            // 3 is numbers of images per row
            if (n/3 *3 == n)
                return  n/3;

            return n/3 +1;
        }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

    }


    int x=5,y=15;

   UIImageView* imgView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 93, 110)];
   imgView1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imgarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 0]];
    x+=103;

   UIImageView* imgView2=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 93, 110)];
    imgView2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imgarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1]];

    x+=103;

    UIImageView* imgView2=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 93, 110)];
    imgView2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imgarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 2]];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView2];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView3];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: did you tried what "[imgarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 0]" is returned. i think it display duplicate images.

Answer (score 0):

**Use @autoreleasepool. Here are details about @autoreleaspool**

The @autoreleasepool statement is doing the same job as before, instead of using the NSAutoreleasePool class. The way the NSAutoreleasePool worked was a bit weird, as creating it caused an effect throughout the whole application; @autoreleasepool creates a scoped area and makes it clearer what's within the pool and when it drains (when it goes out of scope). It's also more efficient according to Apple.

The concept of an autorelease pool is simple, whenever an object instance is marked as autoreleased (for example NSString* str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"] autorelease];), it will have a retain count of +1 at that moment in time, but at the end of the run loop, the pool is drained, and any object marked autorelease then has its retain count decremented. It's a way of keeping an object around while you prepare whatever will retain it for itself.

With ARC, whilst the autorelease keyword isn't used by the developer, the underlying system that manages ARC inserts that for you. (Remember: All ARC is doing is inserting retain, release and autorelease calls for you at the appropriate times). Because of this, the existing AutoreleasePool concept needs to stay around.

If you remove the autorelease pool, your objects will start leaking
For more details [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/)